# Best approach to distributed ID generation per user (web) app synchronised with server

Tags: synchronization, uniqueidentifier, data-synchronization

I am creating a browser-based app which would allow users to have one or more project and each project have many child entities.

I would like for the user to be able to **work offline by default** and synchronise or save changes to a central database that holds all data ( users -> projects -> entities...).

The question relates to mapping generated entity ID values from the clients to IDs on the server in such a way that user's data don't clash due to entities having similar IDs.

My initial thought was to add a 'user_id' column for each entity on the server but make it transparent to the browser-based app.

For example, in a users instance of the app, they create a new project with 'project_id' = 1, when synchronising the server receives the new project and stores the data on equivalent table (which has additional 'user_id' column) and sets the user_id to the user requesting the save operation.

However this approach would require that each table on the server have duo-primary keys. It just feels weird and would like to ask for a better approach that dosent involve (GUIDs).

Thanks.

Comment: I just added a question like this in stackexchange http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/287163/handling-for-ids-in-offline-online-application did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs/GUIDs are just 128-bit numbers, so they have such a large range that it's pretty easy to generate a random one and not worry about conflicts. If you're using 64-bit numbers then randomly generating a number isn't safe so you need a numbering scheme. Normally the database would just handle this with an auto-incrementing field but if you need offline or other client-generated IDs, you can implement this in 2 ways:

**Single incrementing counter**

Contact the server once and reserve a range of numbers. This can be implemented in a single table with a SQL transaction or any database that has atomic counters like Redis. If you need to reserve 1000 numbers, then you send 1000 as an increment. If the previous number was 1234, then 1234 + 1000 = 2234 and now you're safe to use 1235-2234 for your user.

You can set the increment to allow for enough IDs without having to contact the server again. Something like a few million maybe, and with 64-bit numbers, you don't have to worry about running out of space.

**Hi/Lo strategy**

Use the "higher" part of the number as the reservation and the "lower" part as an incrementing ID in your client. So a high part of 12450 + a low part of 234678 = 12450234678 as the actual ID number. This is basically like having two separate key columns but combining into a single number. It requires having a strict split in the number so that you don't have accidental overlaps.

The higher part can be done using a smaller single-digit increment from option 1 above or maybe the user's ID (which could limit the total lifetime numbers available).

---

I've used the incrementing counter option with success in several apps including both server/client offline situations as well as distributed IDs for processing and adding a unique but still incrementing ID to millions of rows across separate servers.